# Symfony2 bad response from query with maxresults and firstresult

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've meet a serious problem with **setMaxResult** and **setFirstResult**.

When i'm trying to get result without **setMaxResults** and **setFirstResult**, it works OK, all rows returned.

When i'm using offset = 0 and limit=10 , it works good, 10 rows returned.

When i'm using offset = 10 and limit = 10 , it return 5 rows (must be 7)

Another example, i've used offset = 0 , limit = 20 ,it returned 15 rows.But it must be 17 rows.

With offset=0 and limit = 30 , it returned all 17 rows .... Why this query works so bad ? With offset = 0 and limit 20, it should have returned all 17 rows... but not 15..

Code :

```
$eligibleCircles = $this->getAllCircles($user);
$results = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        'SELECT
            e
        FROM
            TestBundle:Event e
        LEFT JOIN
            e.eligibleCircles eligibleCircles
        WHERE
            (
                eligibleCircles in (:eligibleCircles)
                OR
                e.owner = :user
            )
                AND
                e.eventStatus = :eventStatus
                AND
                NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT
                    eh
                    FROM
                    TestBundle:EventHidden eh
                    WHERE
                        eh.user = :user
                        AND
                        eh.event = e
                    )
        AND
            e.startDate < :currentDate
        ORDER BY e.startDate DESC
        '
    )
    ->setParameter('eventStatus', 3)
    ->setParameter('eligibleCircles', $eligibleCircles )
    ->setParameter('user', $user )
    ->setParameter('currentDate', new \DateTime('now') )
    ->setFirstResult($offset)
    ->setMaxResults($limitNr)
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: did you test your raw SQL query in mysql/postgresql? it is possible, that your query is causing this behavior on database level and not by ORM

Comment: Get raw sql by replacing `getResult()` with `getQuery()->getSql()` and see what are the values in limit clause of query

Comment: i've tried with getSql() and executing it in mysql...it works fine...

Comment: Limit is a sql function that works on the total number of sql records returned.  Not unfortunately on the number of root objects.  So if an event has more than one eligible circle then limit will not work as desired.  It's just the way sql works.  The only workaround I know of is to first query for eventIds (for which limit will work properly) and then do a second query to get the data for those ids.  In some cases you can use a nested query to achieve the same results.

Comment: Thank you Cerad. It worked. Can you respond to this post normally(without comment). I'll get you right answer !

Answer (score 1):

Cerad is correct with regard to the sql-limit not being useful when you have a join in your query.

If you want to paginate while using Doctrine2 there are some helpfull tools for you available.

Have a look at the documentation here:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html

You need a bit of extra code, but most of the complex stuff is handled for you.
It will also require 1 or 2 additional queries to find the correct records+data. This may or may not be a problem in your situation.